# Mirrored volume in Windows performance - Storage Spaces vs diskpart performance

Tags: windows, storage-spaces, diskpart

I'm currently exploring using Storage Spaces to create a mirrored volume. In benchmarking it against a mirrored volume created with diskpart, I notice that I'm getting twice the throughput on reads. I'm speculating that the diskpart volume is able to make requests of both drives in the mirror in parallel. Is there a way to get that behavior out of the Storage Spaces mirrored volume?

Comment: diskpart is usually creating a software raid 1 afaik whoxh would lead to this

Comment: That seems reasonable with respect to diskpart behavior. My question remains though. Is there a way to get a Storage Spaces mirrored volume have that same behavior?

Comment: To be honestly, no, if i remember correctly to my time beeing mcsa 2016 2 wwy mirrors dont have any performance improvements only a failover

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you configured your particular mirror. If you selected one column then you won’t have any performance boost, it would be one drive performing reads whilst second used only if first returns read error. If you configured two columns - you’ll get double read performance, and so on. Here’s some good summary, sorry it comes from Dell, no Microsoft.

[https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/it-it/storage-md1420-dsms/dsms_bpg_pub-v2/column-count?guid=guid-68f002f4-bc8b-4992-a1cc-b99767fbc86a&lang=en-us#:~:text=Loading%2C%20Please%20wait-,Column%20count,during%20read%2Dand%20write%20operations](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/it-it/storage-md1420-dsms/dsms_bpg_pub-v2/column-count?guid=guid-68f002f4-bc8b-4992-a1cc-b99767fbc86a&lang=en-us#:%7E:text=Loading%2C%20Please%20wait-,Column%20count,during%20read%2Dand%20write%20operations).

**Column count**

*The column count indicates the number of physical disks that Microsoft Storage Spaces stripes data across. The column count has a direct correlation to performance as increasing the column count enables more physical disks to be striped and accessed in parallel during read-and write operations.*